# Should an Init method be in getInstance or the constructor?

Tags: java

I have `getInstance` and a constructor in the same class, but I am not sure where I put my `Init` method.

```
public class UploadService {   
    private Eng mEng;
    private Context mContext;
    private static UploadService INSTANCE;
    private String appDir;

    public static UploadService getInstance(Context context) {
        if (null == INSTANCE) {
            INSTANCE = new UploadService(context);
        }
        return INSTANCE;    
    }

    public UploadService(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        appDir=V8Utils.getAppDir(context);
    }

    public void init(Context cxt) {
        mEng = new Eng(cxt);
        mEng.init(appDir);

    }
}
```

Comment: What should be calling the `init` method?

Comment: As we don't know how your program is called, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Take care if you use this in a multithreading context

Comment: Why do you need an `init` method at all? Why not just perform all initialization in the constructor?

Comment: Every time I call getInstance when I upload files, that is why I am confused. It is good idea to put them in construtor if it works.

Comment: Yes, It is a multithread , every time I will upload four files

Comment: Than you need to syncronize the INSTANCE = new UploadService(context);

Answer (score 2):

I would

- mark `init()` as private method.
- call it in the constructor as it is initializing the state of `UploadService` object using the `Context` object.

I mean:

```
public UploadService(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    appDir=V8Utils.getAppDir(context);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context cxt) {
    mEng = new Eng(cxt);
    mEng.init(appDir);

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I am randomly click active because I use this first time. Thanks, Vikdor.